# Iptables deny all proxy on firewall

Tags: proxy, server, debian, firewall, iptables

i've recently configured a server and after a bit i decided to deny everyone that use a proxy in my Ts3 server, i tried to search some iptables module but nothing, then i'm searching for something like a global proxy list, i'm asking if there's a method to deny all connection from a proxy to my server using iptables or some other program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, i just installed a firewall software such as waf or apf and used their settings to block some whole range of ips, now everything is working well!

Answer (score 0):

If the connections are made "through" the proxy, from the point of view of you server, all the connection are issued by the proxy itself.

So just blocking the ip of the proxy should be enough.

Comment: yes but theres a lot of ip and i need to block atleast all of it

Comment: i will die.... i need some list of network